# Javascript - How to pass data from an ajax call to 3 functions?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I currently have a function called `impactData` that is doing an ajax call to a csv file I created. On success I am passing `data` to my `generateImpactData` which is converting my csv file into an array of objects. At the end of my `generateImpactData` I am passing an array called `impactArr` to `drawBarGraph()`

That is working fine at the moment, but to clean up some code I am now attempting to create a function called `appendImpactData` which will append some of the data to cards I have on my site, unrelated to the bargraph.

Passing `impactArr` to `appendImpactData` function I am getting a return of undefined. Even though `drawBarGraph` has access to the data just fine. I am attempting to now pass this data to `appendImpactData`

My expected outcome is to be able to have access to the impactArr data in both my functions after `generateImpactData`

Here is my code:

```
function impactData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: data,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            appendImpactData(drawBarGraph(generateImpactData(data)))  // trying to pass data to all 3
        },
        error: function (e) {
            // handle exception
            console.log("Error occured while reading resource file: ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

---

first function passing data from the success of the ajax call

```
function generateImpactData(data) {

let dataList = [];
    let csvObjects = $.csv.toObjects(data);

for (var i = 0; i < csvObjects.length; i++) {
        sector = csvObjects[i]["Sector"];
        impact = csvObjects[i]["Impact"];
        data = csvObjects[i]["Date"];

var arrDataListItems = [
            sector,
            impact,
            date,
        ];

        dataList.push(arrDataListItems);

    }


const urlStr = window.location.pathname;
const impactArr = []
const recoverArr = []

if (urlStr.includes('/impact/') {
 impactArr.push(dataList[0][2], dataList[0][3], dataList[0][4])
} else if (urlStr.includes('/recovery/') {
recoverArr.push(dataList[2][2], dataList[2][3], dataList[2][4])
}

return { impactArr: impactArr 
         recoverArr: recoverArr
};

}
```

---

Second function which im passing impactArr to which data is appearing:

```
function drawBarGraph(impactArr) {

console.log(impactArr) // data is returning fine

}
```

---

Third function which impactArr is returning undefined:

```
function appendImpactData(impactArr) {

console.log(impactArr) // returning undefined, I am attempting to access the data here also

}
```

Comment: your not returning from drawBarGraph or appendImpactData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
function drawBarGraph(impactArr) {
  console.log(impactArr) // data is returning fine
} // returns undefined
function appendImpactData(impactArr) {
  console.log(impactArr) // returning undefined, I am attempting to access the data here also
} // returns undefined
```

And calling it like:

```
appendImpactData(
  drawBarGraph(
    generateImpactData(data)
  )
)
```

This calling structure is equivalent to:

```
const first = generateImpactData(data);
const second = drawBarGraph(first);
const third = appendImpactData(second);
```

You are calling each function with the RETURN value of the previously invoked function.

You have 2 options:

1) You can return the data from each function:

```
function generateImpactData(impactArr) {
  // Do stuff
  return impactArr;
}
function drawBarGraph(impactArr) {
  // Do stuff
  return impactArr;
}
function appendImpactData(impactArr) {
  // Do stuff
  return impactArr;
}
```

2) You can call each of them independently if there is no real relationship between them:

```
function impactData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: data,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            const impactArr = generateImpactData(data);
            appendImpactData(impactArr);
            drawBarGraph(impactArr);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            // handle exception
            console.log("Error occured while reading resource file: ", e);
        }
    });
}
```